# NPM deprecated package makes install fail

Tags: npm

I am struggling to understand why trying to run a `npm install` fails when one of the packages in the list is deprecated. A warning shouldn't make the command fail, shouldn't it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit PR. They created a version that hard breaks..
https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/pull/2057
Got to love MS..